# Get methods on a standard class?

Tags: php, stdclass

Is there a way to get all the methods of an instantiated standard class object? I'm talking about an object that has some methods and properties on it, not a fresh stdClass object. `ReflectionClass` seems to work only on classes.

Comment: Does your object have a class or is it classless? (ie. some stdClass mutatant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to get a list of all of the properties, and then iterate over them (or [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) them) and determine which of them [`is_callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php):

```
$myClass = new StdClass;
$myClass->someFunc = function($a) {
    return $a - 1;
};
$myClass->someProperty = 42;

$properties = get_object_vars($myClass);

$methods = array_filter($properties, 'is_callable');
```

I'm not sure if it's my 5.4.39 version of PHP or not, but using the above example and instead doing `var_dump(get_class_methods($myClass));` as @Mike suggested returns an empty array.

Comment: Right, it looks like get_class_methods() only will return ones that are defined in the class(es) that the object is generated from.

Answer (score 2):

Try [get_class_methods()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php), sounds like what you're describing, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: The argument is defined as "The class name or an object instance". The example on the page shows it being used for both (I've used it by just giving it an object, too).

Comment: PHP and function names, gets me everytime XD .. how hard it is to make a function name that is not misleading? Can we get a `get_object_methods()`?

Comment: Yeah, completely agree, it can be misleading. I think at first I passed over it when trying to do it because I thought the same.

Comment: Even just an alias of get_class_methods would make things a little more obvious! Ah, PHP. :P